# Display HTML code when clicked back button in Chrome browser?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am currently experiencing a serious and rare error. My website [luffydecor.com](https://luffydecor.com), when you look at an article and press the button "click go to back" on Chrome browser,the website displays all the html code as if you pressed "ctrl + o".
I build the website with the following features:

- Use laravel framework Use memcached Webserver is litespeed

Comment: it is the caching issue. While I checked your website by disabling cache in Network tabs it works but enabling cache does not work

Comment: also while checking for XHR request on opening the Article page your homepage route is also returning as XHR request so that response might be being flashed while you are hitting back button.

Comment: @AnujShrestha Can you give me a solution please, when i checked , i receive:
X-Firefox-Spdy h2
cache-control no-cache, private
content-type application/json
date Thu, 12 Dec 2019 09:00:44 GMT
server LiteSpeed
strict-transport-security max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
x-powered-by PHP/7.3.12

Comment: When the page is sent initially, content-type is correctly set to text/html but when served from browser cache, the  content-type is application/json, which is why the page is not rendered

Comment: @Snapey I checked and you correct. Could you help me fix this bug. I think, i'll set header on middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the css code in the head of the page and not the footer. The CSS is only being loaded after all the content.

Comment: I don't think that is causing the issue for OP while hitting the back button. Still a valid point for sure

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with this code:

```
 public function index(){
    $key = $this->getCacheKey();
    $models = Cache::remember($key, config('cache.time.news-categories'), function(){
        return $this->model->front()->fPost()->paginate($this->limit);
    });
    return response()->view('frontend.blog.index',['models'=>$models])->header('Content-Type','text/html; charset=UTF-8');
}
```